# If I make an ajax GET request to a file, what exactly do I get back and how do I add it to the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I request a file rather than a page with ajax, what exactly am I getting in return, and how do I add it to the page?

For instance,

```
$.get('myfile.png', function(data) {console.log(data) // buncha jibberish ..
```

or

```
    $.get('mybigfile.pdf', function(data) {console.log(data) // buncha jibberish ..
```

If I print it to the console, I get something like this:

```
1828 0 obj <</Linearized 1/L 1194678/O 1831/E 20241/N 88/T 1158069/H [ 2899 1915]>> endobj
xref 1828 127 0000000016 00000 n 0000005025 00000 n 0000005397 00000 n 0000005555 00000 n 0000005811 00000 n 0000006374 00000 n 0000006412 00000 n 0000006635 00000 n 0000006713 00000 n 0000007168 00000 n 0000007612 00000 n 0000007841 00000 n 0000010512 00000 n 0000010586 00000 n 0000010715 00000 n 0000010806 00000 n......
```

How do I embed the file I requested?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get returned the data that corresponds to the page. If the page is a html page you'll get back the html source. Likewise in your case you are getting a file (png/pdf) which you got as a binary object. You can try converting it as a blob if its a file or if its an image specifically, you can convert it to base64 and  display it into canvas